# How do I convert highly formatted textual table data into HTML?

Tags: php, html, html-table, ascii-art

This ASCII-art table is literally what I need to parse:

```
\---------\-------------\-------------\
| Username| IP          | Connected   |
\---------\-------------\-------------\
| test    | 127.0.0.1   | Yes         |
| atest   | 192.168.2.1 | No          |
| aaa     | 1.2.3.4     | Yes         |
\---------\-------------\-------------\
```

And I have to convert it into HTML like this

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td>IP</td>
            <td>Connected</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>127.0.0.1</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Atest</td>
        <td>192.168.2.1</td>
        <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>1.2.3.4</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Of course the content is only an example. The rows can be 40 like only 3.

Problem Solved

Comment: what have you already tried? do you have some code?

Comment: Wow, really? You couldn't be troubled to use a standard (read: real) serialization format, like JSON, XML, CSV, YAML, etc.?

Comment: @MattBall well it would be better :P ahahaha but the client requires this

Comment: We are here to help. Not do your job for you, nor teach you the basics of programming.

Comment: @datasage nothing... don't know where to begin

Comment: Time to find a better client.

Comment: @MarcB i know how to program software... but i don't know how to do this

Comment: @MarcB Ahahahhahah no sorry :P

Comment: what exactly your file format is?

Comment: @akamomer don't know if this format exists... but as saied my client requires this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. Example is a text file called `my_data.txt` which contains the following which is literally based on your example:

```
\---------\-------------\-------------\
| Username| IP          | Connected   |
\---------\-------------\-------------\
| test    | 127.0.0.1   | Yes         |
| atest   | 192.168.2.1 | No          |
| aaa     | 1.2.3.4     | Yes         |
\---------\-------------\-------------\
```

Here is the PHP script that reads the file into an array using [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and then parses it into a `<table>`:

```
<?php

$data = file('my_data.txt');

if (!empty($data)) {
    $value_array = array();
    // Strip out lines like this `\---------\-------------\-------------\`
    $data = preg_replace("/\\|-/", "", $data);
    $data = trim($data);
    if(!empty($data)) {
        echo '<table border="1">';
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (!empty($value)) {
                echo '<tr>';
                $value_array = preg_split("/|/", $value);
                foreach ($value_array as $table_cell_value) {
                    echo '<td>' . $table_cell_value . '</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: with cvs where simplier i know, but is not what i require

Comment: So, the ASCII-art table structure you posted is literally what you have to work with, @user1494162?

Comment: saadly yes...  this is what the client required so yes...

Comment: @jakeGould i solved another way thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Care to share how you solved this, @user1494162? You could post it as an answer, to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to parse the text file, line by line and split it into fields. Take a look at the `explode` php function which should help you out by splitting each line into the different columns. It should look something like `$columns = explode( "|", $line);`

After you run explode, you receive a php array, which you can loop over using `for` or `foreach` and then print out the html.

You will probably want to run `trim` on each of the parts you get back from the explode, in order to remove all the white spaces, and keep the interesting text only.

If you're unsure how to split the text into lines, you can also use explode for that, using something like `$lines = explode( "\n", $string );`

If you're unsure how to read a text file, checkout the php function `file_get_contents`

That's it, you should have all the building blocks here and it's time to piece them together yourself :)

One more tip, if you're worried about the horizontal separator lines, you can skip them by comparing the first character of every line, and skip over those that start with `\`. Something like `$line[0] == '\'` should do the trick.

Comment: well this would be a good idea... thanks for the tip

Comment: use file('filename.txt) the result will be an array for each line...